# to create a flow to import the data from mysql/postgres/sql server using GCP Cloud data fusion

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I want to create a logical flow in GCP which will import the data (as a source) from any RDBMS (mysql/postgres/sql server/ Oracle) and dump the data in Bigquery (as a destination) .
At present , Cloud data fusion seems to be feasible option .
I tried to import data from mysql cloud instance but it asks for connection arguments which I am not aware.So I can't try later steps.
Do we have any other option which can be used to implement this ?
(Python ..etc)

I tried Cloud data fusion for importing CSV data from GCS and it worked as expected.
My expectation over here is to create a flow which will take data from  oracle/sql server/my sql cloud instance table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for importing data from a MySql Database in Google Cloud https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/connect-to-cloud-sql-source.

Connection arguments are required, otherwise the plugin will not know which DB to connect to and authenticate with it. Maybe if you can post the error you are getting, we can help.

Comment: Thanks Janaki Ram. Now, the updates are we used Datastream in GCP and could bring the data in Bigquery but this approach is  scrapped now and dataflow is to be used.